# Save last clicked element and keep it's css style after page redirect

Tags: jquery, css

I would need help with jquery/css on my website.

I have a list and every list item redirects to a different product page. I want that whenever i click to a list item it gets highlighted with a certain color and after redirection keep my css style.

EDIT: I would need help with localstorage:

```
    jQuery('ul.product-categories li a').click(function(e) {
     localStorage.setItem('latestClicked', e.target);
     jQuery(e.target).css('background-color', 'red');
     jQuery(e.target).css('border-radius', '10px');
   });
```

I tried to save the e.target into local storage, but it needs a string not an object.

How can i store e.target (the clicked element) into localstorage properly, so the getItem function work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) to save and load your preferences

Comment: Regarding your question on saving e.target in localStorage: that's not possible. As a workaround though, you could add an id to the elements (<a data-id="1">...</a>), retrieve it using jQuery(e.target).data('id') and store it then.